# Is MySQL automatically optimizing my repeat queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I noticed something peculiar when testing query speeds on my database. I have two queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `event_history` 
WHERE  `event_details` LIKE  '%joe submitted order%'
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `event_history` 
WHERE  `event_details` LIKE  '%bob submitted order%'
```

The first one is run frequently by the application. The second one is something I just ran manually once. I noticed the first one ran only  0.0035 seconds, but the second one took about 0.2500 seconds. This is unexpected.

Is MySQL optimizing this query somehow? If so, how can I config this, say to make the second query optimized before I put it into production?

Comment: No such optimization is done. There may however be huge differences if you did not yourself optimize your queries / database structure. So if you did not set proper indexes on the columns used in queries. That may well explain differences in seemingly equal queries.

Comment: @arkascha It is a simple table with incrementing id primary index.

Comment: That means your idexes are _not_ set properly. Since you select by the `event_details` column you should definitely create an index for that column! And you should also consider that a `LIKE` operator is exttremely slow compared to all other options. Is there really no way to get around such an expensive query?

Comment: Oh, actually I just realize that MySQL implement a query result cache! That could certainly explain what you see. Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: @arkascha I am aware that avoiding LIKE all together would be more ideal, but not an option.  So I can create indexes for text columns I select? Should I use a "FULLTEXT" index?

Comment: @arkascha that is interesting, reading it now. If you believe that may be playing a part, post as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Why do you think that avoiding the LIKE operator is not an option? Certainly you might not simply replace it, but typically a different approach to such task _is_ possible. Namely a specialized search table, database or even engine.

Comment: Added the cache reference as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @arkascha not that it's not possible, but that it's infrequently used and low priority for anything other than a tweak. Only reason I was researching was to consider removing the query. Is there anything short of restructuring or migrating the data to avoid using a LIKE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL implements a query result cache. That could certainly explain what you see, since you report that an often run query returns faster than a query you execute for the first time.

Take a look here for the details: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Most production systems are better off disabling the QC.  _Every_ modification to a table removes _all_ entries for that table from the QC.